# Hide/reveale js code won't run on IE8 or lower

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, show-hide

Wrote an exercise & solution page, with buttons that start js functions that show or hide the solutions. It works perfectly on up-to-date FF, CH and IE, but on IE8-7-6 when I click the buttons the solutions don't show up and I get an "error on page" message in the status line.
I searched the web for a solution, tried 'regsvr32 jscript.dll', nothing helped.
here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrzJg/), js doesn't work there either but that's probably because I don't know how to use it properly. Anyway the code is there to view.

The problematic code is:
1. html buttons like this one:

```
<button class="button100" onclick="reveal('sol2');">הצג</button>
```

JS 'reveal()' function:

```
function reveal(pId){
        if(pId == 'all_sol'){
            for(var x in solArr){
                document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "<button class=\"button100\" onclick=\"cover('" + x + "');\">הסתר</button>" + solArr[x];
            }
            document.getElementById(pId).innerHTML = "<button class=\"button100\" onclick=\"cover('" + pId + "');\">הסתר את כל הפתרונות</button>";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(pId).innerHTML = "<button class=\"button100\" onclick=\"cover('" + pId + "');\">הסתר</button>" + solArr[pId];
        }   
    }
```

and here is the hole thing:
the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-8-i" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="general_style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exercises_style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="exercises_script.js"></script>
        <title> תרגילים </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <div class="padding_10">
                    <img src="logo.png"></img>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav_bar">
                    <li><a href="operators.htm"> אופרטורים </a></li>
                    <li id="current_nav_bar_li"><a href="exercises.htm"> תרגילים </a></li>
                    <li><a href="concepts.htm"> מושגים </a></li>
                    <li><a href="template.htm">תבנית</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="body">
                <div class="padding_10">

                    <h1> תרגילים ופתרונות </h1>
                    <p> להלן תרגילים שניתנו במהלך הקורס, בצירוף פתרונותיהם. בתרגילים חישוביים הפתרון מפרט כל פעולה חישובית ש JavaScript תבצע באם יוזן התרגיל לחישוב. השורה הראשונה מציגה את הביטוי המוזן לחישוב, כל שורה מכאן ואילך מציגה פעולה אחת של JavaScript. </p>

                    <h2> אלגוריתם ראשון </h2>
                    <h3> תרגיל 1 </h3>
                    <p>
                        הבת של טל יודעת:

                        <ol>
                            <li> לצייר ולכתוב </li>
                            <li> להוסיף 1 לכל מספר </li>
                            <li> להכפיל מספר בעצמו </li>
                            <li> לבדוק זהות בין שני מספרים </li>
                        </ol>

                        יש לכתוב אלגוריתם שבאמצעותו תוכל הבת של טל לחשב שורש ריבועי עבור מספר נתון.
                    </p>

                    <h3> פתרון תרגיל 1 </h3>
                    <p id="sol1">
                        <button class="button100" onclick="reveal('sol1');">הצג</button>
                    </p>


                    <h2> אופרטורים '+', '-', '*' </h2>
                    <h3> תרגיל 2 </h3>
                    <p>
                        פתור את התרגיל על פי סדר הקדימות ב- JavaScript:
                        <div dir="ltr">
                            3 + 2 + 5 + 7 * 3 + 4 * 2 * 3
                        </div>
                    </p>

                    <h3> פתרון תרגיל 2 </h3>
                    <p id="sol2">
                        <button class="button100" onclick="reveal('sol2');">הצג</button>
                    </p>

                    <h3> תרגיל 3 </h3>
                    <p>
                        פתור את התרגיל על פי סדר הקדימות ב- JavaScript:
                        <div dir="ltr">
                            5 - 2 * 4 * 3 - 7 - 9 - 4 - 2 - 1 * 3
                        </div>
                    </p>

                    <h3> פתרון תרגיל 3 </h3>
                    <p id="sol3">
                        <button class="button100" onclick="reveal('sol3');">הצג</button>
                    </p>

                    <h2> סוגריים </h2>
                    <h3> תרגיל 4 </h3>
                    <p>
                        פתור את התרגיל על פי סדר הקדימות ב- JavaScript:
                        <div dir="ltr">
                            (2 + 3) + 5 + (4 + (2 * 2 + 5) - 2) + 3 * 3
                        </div>
                    </p>

                    <h3> פתרון תרגיל 4 </h3>
                    <p id="sol4">
                        <button class="button100" onclick="reveal('sol4');">הצג</button>
                    </p>

                    <h2> מודולו </h2>
                    <h3> תרגיל 5 </h3>
                    <p>
                        פתור את התרגיל על פי סדר הקדימות ב- JavaScript:
                        <div dir="ltr">
                            5 % 2 % 5
                        </div>
                    </p>

                    <h3> פתרון תרגיל 5 </h3>
                    <p id="sol5">
                        <button class="button100" onclick="reveal('sol5');">הצג</button>
                    </p>

                    <h3> תרגיל 6 </h3>
                    <p>
                        פתור את התרגיל על פי סדר הקדימות ב- JavaScript:
                        <div dir="ltr">
                            5 * 3 % 4 * 1 % 6
                        </div>
                    </p>

                    <h3> פתרון תרגיל 6 </h3>
                    <p id="sol6">
                        <button class="button100" onclick="reveal('sol6');">הצג</button>
                    </p>

                    <h2> שמות משתנים </h2>
                    <h3> תרגיל 7 </h3>
                    <p>
                        האם שמות המשתנים להלן חוקיים?
                        <div dir="ltr">
                            <ol class="margin_left">
                                <li> --- </li>
                                <li> ______ </li>
                                <li> 0_ </li>
                                <li> a_a </li>
                                <li> a1321 </li>
                                <li> ab 12 </li>
                                <li> var </li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </p>

                    <h3> פתרון תרגיל 7 </h3>
                    <p id="sol7">
                        <button class="button100" onclick="reveal('sol7');">הצג</button>
                    </p>

                    <h2> השמה </h2>
                    <h3> תרגיל 8 </h3>
                    <p>
                        פתור את התרגיל על פי סדר הקדימות ב- JavaScript:
                        <div dir="ltr">
                            var x, y, z;<br />
                            z = x = 2 * 2 + 3 + ( 4 + 5 ) + ( x = 3 ) * ( y = 2 )
                        </div>
                    </p>

                    <h3> פתרון תרגיל 8 </h3>
                    <p id="sol8">
                        <button class="button100" onclick="reveal('sol8');">הצג</button>
                    </p>

                    <h3> תרגיל 9 </h3>
                    <p>
                        פתור את התרגיל על פי סדר הקדימות ב- JavaScript:
                        <div dir="ltr">
                            var x, y, z;<br />
                            x = ( x = y = z = ( 2 * 5 ) + 3 + 2 % 2 ) % ( z = 2 - 1 * 3 )
                        </div>
                    </p>

                    <h3> פתרון תרגיל 9 </h3>
                    <p id="sol9">
                        <button class="button100" onclick="reveal('sol9');">הצג</button>
                    </p>

                    <p id="all_sol">
                        <button class="button100" onclick="reveal('all_sol');">הצג את כל הפתרונות</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li> כל הזכויות על החומר הלימודי באתר שמורות לטל שחור </li>
                    <li> האתר נבנה על ידי יחזקאל יובל </li>
                    <li> 050-9035454 </li>
                    <li> yovel.zack@gmail.com </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

and JS:

```
var solArr = new Object();

solArr.sol1 = "<ol><li> אם המספר הוא 0 או 1, הוא גם השורש של עצמו. אמרי לאבא שהמספר הוא השורש. אחרת המשיכי לשלב הבא.</li><li> ציירי שלושה ריבועים. </li><li> באמצעי רשמי את המספר שאת השורש שלו צריך לחשב. </li><li> בשמאלי רשמי את המספר 2.</li><li> בימני רשמי את התוצאה של הכפלת המספר הרשום בריבוע השמאלי בעצמו. </li><li> בדקי אם המספר הרשום בריבוע הימני זהה למספר הרשום בריבוע האמצעי. </li><li> אם יש זהות, אמרי לאבא שהמספר הרשום בריבוע השמאלי הוא השורש. אחרת המשיכי לשלב הבא. </li><li> אם אין זהות,  הוסיפי למספר הרשום בריבוע השמאלי 1 וחיזרי לשלב 5.</li></ol>";

solArr.sol2 = "<div dir=\"ltr\"><ol class=\"margin_left\"><li>3 + 2 + 5 + 7 * 3 + 4 * 2 * 3</li><li>3 + 2 + 5 + 21 + 4 * 2 * 3</li><li>3 + 2 + 5 + 21 + 8 * 3</li><li>3 + 2 + 5 + 21 + 24</li><li>5 + 5 + 21 + 24</li><li>10 + 21 + 24</li><li>31 + 24</li><li>55</li></ol></div>";

solArr.sol3 = "<div dir=\"ltr\"><ol class=\"margin_left\"><li>5 - 2 * 4 * 3 - 7 - 9 - 4 - 2 - 1 * 3</li><li>5 - 8 * 3 - 7 - 9 - 4 - 2 - 1 * 3</li><li>5 - 24 - 7 - 9 - 4 - 2 - 1 * 3</li><li>5 - 24 - 7 - 9 - 4 - 2 - 3</li><li>-19 - 7 - 9 - 4 - 2 - 3</li><li>-26 - 9 - 4 - 2 - 3</li><li>-35 - 4 - 2 - 3</li><li>-39 - 2 - 3</li><li>-41 - 3</li><li>-44</li></ol></div>";

solArr.sol4 = "<div dir=\"ltr\"><ol class=\"margin_left\"><li>(2 + 3) + 5 + (4 + (2 * 2 + 5) - 2) + 3 * 3</li><li>() + 5 + () + 3 * 3</li><li>() + 5 + () + 9</li><ol class=\"margin_left\"><li>2 +3</li><li>5</li></ol><li>5 + 5 + () + 9</li><li>10 + () + 9</li><ol class=\"margin_left\"><li>4 + () - 2</li><ol class=\"margin_left\"><li>2 * 2 + 5</li><li>4 + 5</li><li>9</li></ol><li>4 + 9 - 2</li> <li>13 - 2</li> <li>11</li></ol><li>10 + 11 + 9</li><li>21 + 9</li><li>30</li></ol></div>";

solArr.sol5 = "<div dir=\"ltr\"><ol class=\"margin_left\"><li>5 % 2 % 5</li><li>1 % 5</li><li>1</li></ol></div>";

solArr.sol6 = "<div dir=\"ltr\"><ol class=\"margin_left\"><li>5 * 3 % 4 * 1 % 6</li><li>15 % 4 * 1 % 6</li><li>3 * 1 % 6</li><li>3 % 6</li><li>3</li></ol></div>";

solArr.sol7 = "<div dir=\"ltr\"><table><tr><td> --- </td><td> לא חוקי </td></tr><tr><td> ______ </td><td> חוקי </td></tr><tr><td> 0_ </td><td> לא חוקי </td></tr><tr><td> a_a </td><td> חוקי </td></tr><tr><td> a1321 </td><td> חוקי </td></tr><tr><td> ab 12 </td><td> לא חוקי </td></tr><tr><td> var </td><td> לא חוקי </td></tr></table></div>";

solArr.sol8 = "<div dir=\"ltr\"><ol class=\"margin_left\"><li>var x, y, z</li><li>z = x = 2 * 2 + 3 + ( 4 + 5 ) + ( x = 3 ) * ( y = 2 )</li><li>z = x = 2 * 2 + 3 + () + () * ()</li><li>z = x = 4 + 3 + () + () * ()</li><ol><li>x = 3</li><li>3//x == 3</li></ol><ol><li>y = 2</li><li>2//y == 2</li></ol><li>z = x = 4 + 3 + () + 3 * 2</li><li>z = x = 4 + 3 + () + 5</li><li>z = x = 7 + () + 5</li><ol><li>4 + 5</li><li>9</li></ol><li>z = x = 7 + 9 + 5</li><li>z = x = 16 + 5</li><li>z = x = 21</li><li>z = 21//x == 21</li><li>21//z == 21</li></ol></div>";

solArr.sol9 = "<div dir=\"ltr\"><ol class=\"margin_left\"><li>x = ( x = y = z = ( 2 * 5 ) + 3 + 2 % 2 ) % ( z = 2 - 1 * 3 )</li><li>x = () % ()</li><ol><li>x = y = z = () + 3 + 2 % 2</li><li>x = y = z = () + 3 + 0</li><li>x = y = z = () + 3</li><ol><li>2 * 5</li><li>10</li></ol><li>x = y = z = 10 + 3</li><li>x = y = z = 13</li><li>x = y = 13 //z == 13</li><li>x = 13 //y == 13</li><li>13 //x == 13</li></ol><li>x = 13 % ()</li><ol><li>z = 2 - 1 * 3</li><li>z = 2 - 3</li><li>z = -1</li><li>-1 //z == -1</li></ol><li>x = 13 % -1</li><li>x = 0</li><li>0 //x == 0</li></ol></div>";

function reveal(pId){
    if(pId == 'all_sol'){
        for(var x in solArr){
            document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "<button class=\"button100\" onclick=\"cover('" + x + "');\">הסתר</button>" + solArr[x];
        }
        document.getElementById(pId).innerHTML = "<button class=\"button100\" onclick=\"cover('" + pId + "');\">הסתר את כל הפתרונות</button>";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(pId).innerHTML = "<button class=\"button100\" onclick=\"cover('" + pId + "');\">הסתר</button>" + solArr[pId];
    }   
}


function cover(pId){
    if(pId == "all_sol"){
        for(var x in solArr){
            document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "<button class=\"button100\" onclick=\"reveal('" + x + "');\">הצג</button>";
        }
        document.getElementById(pId).innerHTML = "<button class=\"button100\" onclick=\"reveal('" + pId + "');\">הצג את כל הפתרונות</button>";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(pId).innerHTML = "<button class=\"button100\" onclick=\"reveal('" + pId + "');\">הצג</button>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to localize the code which causes the trouble and strip out all un-needed code.

Comment: Also, try getting a developement-tool such as Firebug. It clearly states the problem om the jsFiddle: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://fiddle.jshell.net/QrzJg/show/exercises_script.js" Might be a contributing factor. Clicking on a buton yields the following error: "ReferenceError: reveal is not defined"

Comment: OK now I get you. I'll try to do that.

Comment: Here, the specific code that case the trouble. Sorry, didn't get your meaning at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uhh, a lot of things don't work on IE6 or 7. I suggest you drop support for them. Even Microsoft doesn't support it anymore! However, if you really need to go ahead with this, then use jQuery, which should fix your problems (when used correctly)

Comment: thanks, I can drop support for IE7-6, no problem. But the JS code don't work on IE8 as well. Computers with IE8 are still widely used, at least were I am from, so I wouldn't like to have to drop support for them either...

Comment: Ahh ok, IE8 not working is a problem :P. Where's the code btw? As pointed above, the link doesn't work. Can you try pastebin?

Comment: thanks for your patience with me. Sometimes I just don't get over the language barrier :) I added the html and js to the original post.

Comment: Anyway I'll take your answer, jQuery may be my best bet for now.

Comment: and if you still see errors, f12 opens up the console for IE8 and any error message plus their corresponding lines. I'm ready to help her if needed, so feel free to ask if you still have questions :)

Comment: Kpower, your tip about f12 is worth gold to me. I learned that the .innerHTML property will act like this when used on some html tags, so I replaced the relevant <p> tags with <div> tags. It works perfectly now, and f12 will probably help me forever now. thanks for your help!